# Баг со слайдером картинок при беспорядочном клике на ссылку

Tags: jquery

Есть слайдер картинок. При клике по стрелкам `ul` нормально смещается влево и вправо... То есть при клике по стрелкам меняется позиция `ul`:

```
$('#vpered').click(function(){
    $('ul').css('marginLeft', '-100px'); 
});
```

Весь код писать не стал. С этим проблем нет, все нормально работает.

А вот когда я применяю метод `animate`, и кликаю по стрелкам, не дожидаясь, пока `ul` сместится, он смещается не так, как надо...

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#vpered').click(function(){
    $('ul').animate('marginLeft', '=-100px'); 
});
```

Comment: Не помогло

Answer (score 0):

А что если блокировать анимацию, на время её исполнения? Тогда нельзя будет кликнуть, пока анимация не завершилась.

```
logicAnimate = true;
$('#vpered').click(function(){
  if(logicAnimate){
    logicAnimate = false;
    $('ul').animate({marginLeft : '=-100px'}, 500, function(){
      logicAnimate = true;
    });
  } 
});
```